# Oracle pl/sql forall: how to count actual number of inserted lines with tablespace full (1654) error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL functions that bulk insert many lines into a table.
I want to know how many lines are correctly inserted and how many have problems (Oracle version 11g).

I did something like:

```
   (...)
   BEGIN
       FORALL i IN 1 .. num SAVE EXCEPTIONS
           insert into mytable values (myarr(i));
       EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
           l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
           FOR i in 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
               dbms_output.put_line('Error #' || i || ',
                 iter: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX ||
                 ', code: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE ||
                 ', ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
           END LOOP;
   END;

   FOR i IN 1 .. num LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Statement #' || i || ' inserted ' ||
         SQL%BULK_ROWCOUNT(i) || ' rows.');
   END LOOP;

   commit;
   (...)
```

Usually it works OK giving the exact number or lines having errors (duplicate id and so on) and I can list them one per line.

The problem comes when the tablespace runs out of space (it's something that is not under my control...): in this case, even if the forall inserted ZERO rows, it seems it worked OK.
For instance if I insert 10 lines I get:

```
Error #1, iter: 11, code: 1654, ORA-01654: unable to extend index TEST_SOL11_XS43018_USER_FULL.SYS_C00146274 by 128 in tablespace USERS_FULL
Statement #1 inserted 1 rows.
Statement #2 inserted 1 rows.
Statement #3 inserted 1 rows.
Statement #4 inserted 1 rows.
Statement #5 inserted 1 rows.
Statement #6 inserted 1 rows.
Statement #7 inserted 1 rows.
Statement #8 inserted 1 rows.
Statement #9 inserted 1 rows.
Statement #10 inserted 1 rows.
```

So I get a SINGLE error, that is declared at iteration #11 (but my loop is 1..10). It seems that the previous 10 iterations worked, at least it seams printing SQL%BULK_ROWCOUNT(i)

The fact if that no raw was really written, because the tablespace was full (and I double checked id by counting lines before and after).

If there a way I can check how many lines were *really* inserted into the table?

Comment: You actually have a variable called `num` which has value 10; you aren't using `myarr.count` and `SQL%BULK_ROWCOUNT.count`?

Comment: It's only an snippet to show the problem. I used num because is shorter to write and read.

Comment: Yes, but you've suggested your loop is 1..10,; with num that looks like both loops. It *appears* obvious that myarr has > 10 entries, and 10 were successfully inserted. The TS wasn't full for the first 10 rows inserted. Maybe; not sure what it does in that case. Is there no other activity - you're really sure the 10 rows weren't really inserted?

Comment: I'm 100% sure no row was inserted.

Comment: I'm 100% sure no row was inserted.
I double checked it in many ways. For instance I did count(*) before and after the PL/SQL block, and it gave me the same value.
Another reason I'm sure is because I tried to insert a single row in this way:
        insert into mytable values (1);
and Oracle gave me the ORA-01654 error.
If it is not possible to insert a single line, in the same way is not possible to "bulk" insert more than one line.

Comment: The strange thing is that Oracle fills the SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS array with a single record having ERROR_INDEX set to 11.
That index is supposed to be an index pointing to the myarr item causing the error. The loop was for record 1 .. 10,
so there was no record number 11.

Comment: After the insert stmt , print  'sql%rowcount' to know how many successfully inserted.

Answer (score 0):

An exception is raised, so the transaction is rolled back. So, no rows are inserted.

Comment: I's a bulk insert, so if, for instance, you try to insert 1000 rows, you can get 5 exceptions that means 995 lines were inserted and 5 weren't.
The "SAVE EXCEPTIONS" tells Oracle to save all the exceptions in an array.
This means that an exceptions doesn't cause an automatic rollback.